# Parse String to Tree Using Stack

Tags: python, recursion, tree, stack

In the interest of full disclosure, this *was* HW, but the assignment was already due.

If we define a simple tree as follows:

```
class Tree (object):
    __slots__ = "node","children"
    def __init__(self,node,children=[]):
        self.node = node
        self.children = children
```

How do we build a tree from a string? In the string model, "NIL" signifies the end of a tree. So, the string `1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL` would return a tree fashioned like `t = Tree(1, [Tree(2, [Tree(5, []), Tree(3, [Tree(4)])])])`. The solution can use recursion and/or a stack. I thought I understood stacks and recursion, but I cannot figure out this problem. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
To add some further information, we can print the tree like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "(%s)" % " ".join(map(str,[self.node]+self.children))
```

I couldn't get anywhere close to creating a tree, and printing it. All I could think of was creating a string that *looks like* the string to create a tree. I have:

```
def delinearize(self, linear_string):
    @staticmethod
    tree_data = linear_string.split()
    tree_str = ""
    if tree_data[0] == "NIL":
        print "Tree needs initial root node"
        return
    for entry in tree_data:
        if entry != "NIL":
                tree_str += "Tree("+entry+", ["
        elif entry == "NIL":
                tree_str += "]),"
```

Comment: Write the tree using just brackets: `(1 (2 (5) (3 (4))))`. Note that `(` always comes before a number and `)` replaces `NIL`. See how `(` "goes down" a level, and `)` "goes up" a level? Does this give you any ideas?

Comment: @nneonneo - Thanks, but give the current code, would that create an actual tree, or just something that looks like a tree?

Comment: Heh, not what I intended, though `delinearize` could really make a `Tree` if you just call `eval` on the result, even if that is evil. Why is that, though? The Python parser uses a stack to parse the nested constructors. Maybe you could do likewise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, for this input:

```
1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL
```

You say this should be the result (note I just formatted your version for easier understanding):

```
Tree(1, [
    Tree(2, [
        Tree(5, []),
        Tree(3, [
            Tree(4)
        ])
    ])
])
```

Which "looks like" this:

```
  1
  |
  2
 / \
5   3
    |
    4
```

From this (and nneonneo's helpful comment) we can determine how these trees are built from strings.  It seems to work like this:

1. Start with a theoretical root node, considered the "current" one.
2. For each non-NIL value, add it as a child of the current node, and mark it as the new current node.  That is, descend.
3. For each NIL value, mark the parent of the current node as the new current node.  That is, ascend.
4. When the theoretical root node is reached again, we're done (and the string should be fully consumed).

Note that the trailing NILs to get back to the root can probably be elided if you want to save space.  On the other hand, including them supports the sanity check at the end.

With the outline I gave above, it can be implemented in an iterative fashion, with no recursion.  Some folks would prefer a recursive solution, but either way is equally powerful, so the latter is left as an exercise!

Comment: Thanks, I should've clarified that I do understand what needs to be done, but don't understand, pragmatically, how to do this in Python. For example, I feel like I could do this in C++, using a stack of pointers. But, using your example, how do I do (3), i.e. ascend the tree?

Comment: In Python, basically everything is treated like a reference (almost, for the purposes of this discussion).  And you can have `None` where you'd have `NULL` in C.  So if in C++ you would keep pointers to the parent of each node, you can do precisely the same in Python (just without the special `*` syntax).

Answer (score 0):

So let's say that we know the following two things:

- if you read NIL from the input string you know that you read and empty tree.
- if you read a number then you have a non empty tree with the root containing said number and you still need to read two trees (one for the left child and one for the right child) from the input string.

Now we are ready to read the tree :). Assuming the following C like structure (i'll let you do this in python as an exercise, and is way cleaner in python):

```
struct tree {
   int value;
   tree *left;
   tree *right;
}
```

and some hand waving basically a method that takes a char*, returns the first token and changes the input string to point at the next token) at the input stream one can do:

```
tree *readTree(char *&inputString) {
   char *token = read_next_token(inputString); 
   if (strcmp(token, "NIL") {
      // empty tree .. we return
      return NULL;
   }

   struct tree* node = malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
   node->value = token_as_int(token);

   // note that after the readTree is called the inputString will be modified
   // that's why i defined it to take a reference to a pointer of chars.
   node->left = readTree(inputString);
   node->right = readTree(inputString);
   return node; 
}
```

and the read_next_token is defined as:

```
char *read_next_token(char*&inputString) {
  char *token = inputString;

  while ( *inputString != ' ' )
    inputString++;

  *inputString = 0; // make the token a null terminated string.

  while ( *inputString == ' ' ) inputString++;

  return token;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do understand how to do it in C++, but what's the equivalent of a c++ pointer, in Python?

Comment: You don't need pointers at all :). They are just a trick here so that the solution looks more complicated than it really is. You just need a struct with the ability to record children and the ability to turn a string into a list of token that you can modify when you read a token from it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []

    def __iadd__ (self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append (child)
        return self

    def fromString (string):
        return Tree.fromList (string.split () ) [0]

    def fromList (list):
        node = Tree (list [0] )
        list = list [1:]
        while list [0] != 'NIL':
            child, list = Tree.fromList (list)
            node += child
        return node, list [1:]

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '{}{}'.format (self.value, ': {}'.format (self.children) if self.children else '')

t = Tree.fromString ('1 2 5 NIL 3 4 NIL NIL NIL NIL')
print (t)

t = Tree.fromString ('1 2 NIL 3 4 NIL 5 NIL 6 NIL NIL 7 NIL NIL')
print (t)
```